# given 2 time series, create a column and forward fill some dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, fill

Hello I have 2 time series, one with daily dates and one with specific dates. I have created a df whose rows show daily dates. I would like to create a column where to ffill the date until the row shows a date contained in the time series with specific dates.

What I have:

daily time series

```
  Date

13/03/2017
10/03/2017
09/03/2017
08/03/2017
....
15/02/2017
14/02/2017
13/02/2017
10/02/2017
09/02/2017
08/02/2017
07/02/2017
06/02/2017
03/02/2017
02/02/2017
01/02/2017
31/01/2017
30/01/2017
```

and the time series with specific dates

```
   Date
13/03/2017
06/02/2017
09/01/2017
05/12/2016
07/11/2016
11/10/2016
06/09/2016
08/08/2016
```

What I would like to get is the following

```
                  Start
13/03/2017      06/02/2017
10/03/2017      06/02/2017
09/03/2017      06/02/2017
08/03/2017      06/02/2017
....
15/02/2017      06/02/2017
14/02/2017      06/02/2017
13/02/2017      06/02/2017
10/02/2017      06/02/2017
09/02/2017      06/02/2017
08/02/2017      06/02/2017
07/02/2017      06/02/2017
06/02/2017      06/02/2017
03/02/2017      09/01/2017
02/02/2017      09/01/2017
01/02/2017      09/01/2017
31/01/2017      09/01/2017
30/01/2017      09/01/2017
02/02/2017      09/01/2017
01/02/2017      09/01/2017
31/01/2017      09/01/2017
30/01/2017      09/01/2017
```

Basically, at 06/02/2017 it should still give me 06/02/2017 but at 05/02/2017 the fill should switch to the next date from the second time series, i.e. 09/01/2017.

I believe it should be some sort of ffill or resample, but I can't think of a method to implement this!

Any suggestion is appreciated a lot!
Thanks!

Comment: If output row is `06/02/2017      06/02/2017` then first row is not `2017-03-13 2017-03-13` ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need first convert them [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)s, then find same values by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and replace by [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html), last back filling missing values:

```
#s1, and s2 are Series
df1 = pd.to_datetime(s1, format='%d/%m/%Y').to_frame('date')
s = pd.to_datetime(s2, format='%d/%m/%Y')

#s1, and s2 are columns Date
#df1 = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y').to_frame('date')
#s = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

df1['Start'] = df1['date'].where(df1['date'].isin(s)).bfill()
```

Another solution:

```
df1.loc[df1['date'].isin(s), 'Start'] = df1['date']
df1['Start'] = df1['Start'].bfill()
print (df1)
         date      Start
0  2017-03-13 2017-03-13
1  2017-03-10 2017-02-06
2  2017-03-09 2017-02-06
3  2017-03-08 2017-02-06
4  2017-02-15 2017-02-06
5  2017-02-14 2017-02-06
6  2017-02-13 2017-02-06
7  2017-02-10 2017-02-06
8  2017-02-09 2017-02-06
9  2017-02-08 2017-02-06
10 2017-02-07 2017-02-06
11 2017-02-06 2017-02-06
12 2017-02-03        NaT
13 2017-02-02        NaT
14 2017-02-01        NaT
15 2017-01-31        NaT
16 2017-01-30        NaT
```

Replace missing last values is a bit complicated, because possible not exist next values in second `Series`:

```
next_val = next(iter(s[(s == df1['Start'].min()).shift().fillna(False)]), np.nan)

df1['Start'] = df1['Start'].fillna(next_val)
print (df1)
         date      Start
0  2017-03-13 2017-03-13
1  2017-03-10 2017-02-06
2  2017-03-09 2017-02-06
3  2017-03-08 2017-02-06
4  2017-02-15 2017-02-06
5  2017-02-14 2017-02-06
6  2017-02-13 2017-02-06
7  2017-02-10 2017-02-06
8  2017-02-09 2017-02-06
9  2017-02-08 2017-02-06
10 2017-02-07 2017-02-06
11 2017-02-06 2017-02-06
12 2017-02-03 2017-01-09
13 2017-02-02 2017-01-09
14 2017-02-01 2017-01-09
15 2017-01-31 2017-01-09
16 2017-01-30 2017-01-09
```